# Magento 2 : All field DIsable in Search Engine Robots Section Admin

Tags: magento2

From Admin panel , in Content-> Configuration -> Search Engine Robots , all filed is disable. I am not able to edit any field , is there any setting

Any idea please Share [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a **Store View** theme entry in Design Configuration? Try editing its ***parent's theme***. Usually the first entry. You can edit Search Engine Robots there and the rest will be updated also including this one.